# Integrating a function in R

Tags: r, statistics, integration, normal-distribution, montecarlo

I was hoping to get some help integrating a function that is based on a random variable. The function is to get an expected value of a continuous distribution.

Here is the code that I have so far.

```r
montecarlo <- function(r,v,t,x,k) {
  y <- rnorm(1)
  e <- (y*(x*exp((-v*sqrt(t)*y)+((r-(.5*v^2))*t))-k))
  MCOP <- exp(-r*t)*integrate(e, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf)
  if((x*exp((-v*sqrt(t)*y)+((r-(.5*v^2))*t))-k) > 0) {
    return(MCOP)
  } else {
    return(0)
  } 
}
```

If I type in for instance: `montecarlo(.03, .65, 3, 34, 30)`

I get an error message that reads:

> Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) :
> object 'e' of mode 'function' was not found

Comment: I want to integrate with respect to y all of the other variables x,v,t,r,and k are going to be given.

Comment: Y is supposed to be a randomly generated number and the function which which I am trying to program will give me the expected value of a continuous distributions (which is the integral from -inf to inf of y*f(y) dy

Comment: if you read `?integrate` the first parameter is a "an R function ..." Your code is calculating a  a value for e. I don't know `integrate` so I cannot advise much, but I think you need to define another function and pass it as a parameter to `integrate`

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple issues, but the first one causing the error is that `e` should be a function.
Namely, instead of

```
y = rnorm(1)
e = (y*(x*exp((-v*sqrt(t)*y)+((r-(.5*v^2))*t))-k))
```

you should have

```
e = function(y){y*(x*exp((-v*sqrt(t)*y)+((r-(.5*v^2))*t))-k)}
```

Comment: Well, `integrate` needs a function as the first argument. And " 
I want to integrate with respect to y" seems to be a clear indication that `e` should be a function. Maybe this would be enough of a push for the author to move forward. Solving one issue at a time.